# How to create authentication token in the HTTP header request for Json view

Tags: views, users, tokens

I have a view listing some fields from a content type then i made it in a Json format using [View DataSource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module, all is ok with me tell now

i want to add authentication token in the header request to restrict any user to access this json view

any module or code help me,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

views_datasource uses the standard drupal session to authenticate.

First set the permissions on the view to what you want. And test this in the browser.

then you can go onto your user authentication. 
Im assuming that you're using ajax to call the view, in a headless mode ?

then you've got 2 options

1) Make the users log into the Drupal site somehow first - that will then give them a session , and when they call that ajax request, the session will be sent.

2) Authenticate the user from your code - you can do this with the services module. you can follow this post https://www.drupal.org/node/910598 for more information